# jQuery animations cancel each other?

Tags: jquery, animation, gallery, element, fade

HundleyDeveloping.com/work/

For some reason, if I play one animation by mousing over, it works fine, but then until I refresh the other animation will not play.

jQuery

```
$(".image-container").hover( 
    function() {
        $(".image").animate({ height: "400", width: "574"}, "fast");
        $(".image").css("z-index", "2");
        $(".image-container-two").css("z-index", "1");
        $(".caption").stop().fadeOut("fast");
    }, function() {
        $(".image").animate({ height: "200", width: "287"}, "fast");
        $(".image").css("z-index", "0");
        $(".image-container-two").css("z-index", "0");
        $(".caption").fadeIn("fast");       
        }
);

$(".image-container-two").hover(
    function() {
        $(".image-two").animate({ height: "400", width: "462"}, "fast");
        $(".image-two").css("z-index", "2");
        $(".image-container").css("z-index", "1");
        $(".caption-two").fadeOut("fast");
    }, function() {
        $(".image-two").animate({ height: "200", width: "231"}, "fast");
        $(".image-two").css("z-index", "0");
        $(".image-container").css("z-index", "0");
        $(".caption-two").fadeIn("fast");           
        }
);
```

CSS

```
.image-container {

    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px outset #666666;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 2;

}

.image-container-two {

    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px outset #666666;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    left: 325px;
    z-index: 1;

}

.image {

    z-index: inheit;
    width: 287px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-right: 3px;

}

.image-two {

    z-index: inheit;
    width: 231px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-right: 3px;

}

.caption {

    z-index: inherit;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 287px;
    height: 30px;
    opacity:0.7;
    filter:alpha(opacity=70);
    margin: 5px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    font-family: Perpetua, Baskerville, "Big Caslon", "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "URW Palladio L", "Nimbus Roman No9 L", serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    line-height: 30px;

}

.caption-two {

    z-index: inherit;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 231px;
    height: 30px;
    opacity:0.7;
    filter:alpha(opacity=70);
    margin: 5px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    font-family: Perpetua, Baskerville, "Big Caslon", "Palatino Linotype", Palatino,      "URW Palladio L", "Nimbus Roman No9 L", serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    line-height: 30px;

}
```

HTML

```
<div class="image-container">
                        <img src="../images/templateone.jpg" class="image" alt=""/>
                        <br />
                        <span class="caption">Template #1</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="image-container-two">
                        <img src="../images/templatetwo.jpg" class="image-two" alt=""/>
                        <br />
                        <span class="caption-two">Template #2</span>
                    </div>
```

Help please! Cannot figure out why these elements appear to be "jealous" of each other.

Comment: What 'other' animation? The animation from the other image or the function in the handlerOut (second of the `hover`) function ?

Comment: If I play the animation on one image, I can take my mouse on an off and repeat that animation as many times as I want, but only for that image. After running an animation on one of the images, the other image animation will not start on hover.

Comment: They seem to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/gYQw7/

Comment: You're right, but its actually broken in a different way. Template #1 the z-index does not change.

Comment: So, why isn't it working on my page? *Scratch Head*

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, something with the z-index was messing with it. I simply removed everything in the animation having to do with z-index, and it worked fine. Thanks guys, cheers!